Is there a positive function $f(x) >0$ defined on $(100,+\infty)$ such that $0\le f'(x)\le 1$ and $f''(x)+\frac12 \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \le 0$?
If $g''(x)+\frac12 \frac{g(x)}{x^2}=0$, we can solve the equation
$$
g(x)=C_1 \sqrt{x}\cos (\frac12 \ln x)+C_2\sqrt{x}\sin (\frac12 \ln x).
$$
On $(100,+\infty)$, $g(x)$ can be positive, zero, negative.
I want to prove that  in the question such $f$ does not exist. Argue by contradiction, suppose that such f exists. Consider
$$
(\frac{g}{f})'=\frac{g'f-f'g}{f^2}.
$$
Since
$$
g(x)=\sqrt{C_1^2+C_2^2} \sqrt{x} \sin(\frac12 \ln x+a)
$$
Then
$$
g'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sqrt{C_1^2+C_2^2}x^{-\frac12}\sin(\frac12 \ln x+a+\frac{\pi}{4})
$$
So how to get a contradiction?
